# Gostaria de printar na tela caso o usuário não exista no banco de dados, não aparece nada no meu terminal, desculpem a falta de indentação no código

Tags: mysql, python, visual-studio-code

```
def del_user(usuario):  
   cursor = conexao.cursor()  
   try:  
       leitura = f'SELECT usuario FROM Cliente where usuario = "{usuario}"'  
       cursor.execute(leitura)  
       consulta = cursor.fetchall()        
       for linha in consulta:  
           if linha[2] == usuario:     
               comando = f'DELETE FROM Cliente WHERE usuario = "{usuario}"'  
               cursor.execute(comando)  
               conexao.commit()  
               print('Usuário Deletado')  
           else:  
               print('Inexistente')  
   except Exception as erro:  
       print(f'Falha ao deletar usuário {erro}')                
   cursor.close()        
   conexao.close()
```

Comment: eu alterei a parte leitura = f'SELECT usuario FROM Cliente where usuario = "{usuario}"' para leitura = f'SELECT * FROM Cliente where usuario = "{usuario}"' NADA MUDOU

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: que código complexo, verificar pra depois fazer delete.... faz direto o `DELETE`, depois olhar o valor de `cursor.rowcount` que vai retornar o numero de linhas afetadas pelo comando, se for zero, é porque o usuário não existia

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar o "Exception", todos os erros que ocorrerem irão ser tratados da mesma forma. Serão printados como "Falha ao deletar usuário {erro}"

```
except Exception as erro:  
   print(f'Falha ao deletar usuário {erro}')
```

Se você quer tratar cada mensagem de erro de forma especifica recomendo fazer dessa forma:

```
except Exception as erro:  
   if "error 1" in erro.__str__():
       pass

   elif "error 2" in erro.__str__():
       pass
```

assim você pode criar condições para tratar o seu erro.

Ah! Se você estiver usando a biblioteca do MySql, você consegue importar as mensagens de erro para facilitar sua vida lol.

```
import mysql.connector.errors
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).